# abas-ERP (FO-Language): Exact time difference between 2 abas dates

Tags: erp, abas

Is there any FO-native possibility for getting the exact difference between two abas date objects?

I have a AJO-based solution comparing two Calendar-Objects, but it's too slow for my use-case (it's called to many times) and I hope there is a native solution.

And what is the highest accuracy the abas dates (GD-Fields) can represent? Just Seconds or is there a way to get a UNIX-time-stamp or something comparable for a higher precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the GP4 type.

```
.type GD19 xdbegin xdend
.type GP4  xgdiff
.formula U|xdbegin = "1.1.2015 00:00:00"
.formula U|xdend   = "1.1.2016 00:00:00"
.formula U|xgdiff  = U|xdend-U|xdbegin
'U|xgdiff'
```

output will be 365D00h00m00s

Now you can convert it e.g. into seconds:

```
.type text xtcmd
.type int  xisec
.formula U|xtcmd = "formula U|xisec = " + F|regreplace(F|regreplace(F|regreplace(F|regreplace('U|xgdiff', "D", "*24*60*60+"), "h", "*60*60+"), "m", "*60+"), "s", "")
.'U|xtcmd'
```

As far as I know "seconds" is the highest precision you can use in FO.
If you need more, you have to use (as you already mentioned) UNIX-time-stamps

Comment: Do you know a possibility to get the seconds of a GP4 type? Or do I have to parse it?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to parse it. What exactly are you trying to do with the "seconds" part?

Comment: It's just for the output. In some cases it's more pretty to see 95 seconds instead of 1m35s. But this GP4 type is a good solution and works for me. thanks =)

Comment: If a a GP4 type could return the result in seconds it would be much easier to convert in different output formats.

Comment: Now I have a use case where I need a percentage part of a time difference. Here an easy second conversion would be helpful too, because you can not calculate with the GP4 (only addition and subtraction).

Comment: Just see my answer. I already showed how to convert a GP4 value into seconds.

Comment: Yes I know... but I don't like the solution and it's annoying that abas have such horrible methods for handling dates and times. It was more a flame comment, sorry ;D

Comment: And I like your solution!!!! What I don't like is the FO-solution for handling time and dates ^^